# Limit $\lim _{x \to -3} \frac{\frac 1{ax} + \frac 13}{b x^3 + 27} = - \frac 1{3^5}$

Tags: limits

> $a,b$ are positive integer

Substitute $x=-3$

$= \dfrac{-\frac {1}{3a} + \frac 13}{-27b + 27} $

So I conclude :

$ -\dfrac {1}{3a} + \dfrac 13$ is definite positive.

$-27b + 27$ is defnitie negative.

Whenever I try 
$ -\dfrac {1}{3a} + \dfrac 13 = 1$ or

$ -\dfrac {1}{3a} + \dfrac 13 = \frac 13$ i always get $a \neq$ integer. So, where am I wrong here?

Comment: how come the numerator becomes -1/3a+1/3? It should be 1/a+1/3? Typo or what?

Comment: Ok. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: after the question change, we now answer the question for $\frac{\frac{1}{ax}+\frac{1}{3}}{bx^{3}+27}$ instead.

We exclude easily the case and $a\not=1,b=1$. The case $a=1$ is handled below. Assuming $a\not=1,b\not=1$, then this reduce to the problem of $\frac{-\frac{1}{3a}+\frac{1}{3}}{-27b+27}=-\frac{1}{3^{5}}$ by plugging in $x=-3$. Equate the numerator to get $\frac{3^{5}}{3}(1-\frac{1}{a})=-27(1-b)$ or simplify: $3(1-\frac{1}{a})=b-1$ so $b-1<3$. Try both possibilities we get the final answer.

EDIT: since the question had been edited, I guess I need to account for the case $a=1$ now. If $a=1$ and $b\not=1$, then the limit is clearly $0$ since the numerator goes to $0$ but the denominator doesn't, so we can eliminate this case. So we check $a=1,b=1$ then this is $\frac{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3}}{x^{3}+27}=\frac{\frac{3+x}{3x}}{(x+3)(x^{2}-3x+9)}=\frac{1}{3x(x^{2}-3x+9)}$. Evaluate this in the limit give us $-\frac{1}{3^{5}}$, so this also count as an answer.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the question

Comment: So to solve it using trial and error? By try if a =1 a = b or a not b?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: what do you mean trial and error? We narrow down to 3 possibilities and check them.

Comment: Ok. I understand the part $a \neq 1$ and $b=1$ excluded. I understand the part $a, b \neq 1$ then we get the limit to $x=-3$. And i understand the part that $a=1$ $b\neq 1$ the function is 0. And when $a,b=1$ it satisfied the question. So the answer is $a,b $ = 1?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: we don't get $b<0$, in fact we know $b>0$ by the requirement of the problem. After considering the 3 previous cases, the only case left is $a,b=1$.

Comment: So 3 possibilities are $a,b \neq 1$ we get $b<4$? and $a=1,b\neq 1$ we get limit = 0? and $a,b =1$ we satisfied the question? And there are no positive integer that satisfied the question but $a,b =1$ ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: there are solution for $a,b!=1$ but I did not write out explicitly because it's already narrow down to just 2 possibilities which you can check.

Comment: Ok. So what is a and b then? a = 1 and b = 1 right? What is 2 possibility?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: there is $a,b=1$, and 2 possibilities for $a,b!=1$ because we narrow it down to only 2 possible values for $b$.

Comment: Make it simpler please.. what is the answet then? Why there are more than 1 possibilites? We checked only a =1 and b =1 ,that satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Hint. You can start by simplifying the equation 
$$\dfrac{3+a}{a(1-b)} = -\dfrac{1}3$$
Then from the equation find the relation between $a$ and $b$,
$$a=...$$
$$b=...$$
Then find $a$ for a value of $b$, e.g. $b=10$. In that case $a$ is not an integer, by what can you multiply $a$ to get an integer? For instance, get $b$ from the new $a$ after it's be multiplied by $2$. What can you infer from the $a$ and $b$ relation equations, so that they're both positive and integer?

Comment: Ok. I have edited the question